# Bucle y precio medio

Tags: java, netbeans

¿Pueden ayudarme a resolver esto? Tengo el siguiente código:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Ejemplo {

public static final int IDIOMAMAX = 3;
public static final int IDIOMAMIN = 0;
public static final int PRECIOMAX = 100;
public static final int PRECIOMIN = 1;
public static final int MAXINTENTOS = 5;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int contador = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int ordMed, precio, idioma;
    float precioMedio = 0f;
    int arreglo[][] = new int[2][10];
    x = 0;

    i = 0;
    do {
        System.out.println("Escoja un idioma: ");
        System.out.println("Inglés, igual 0");
        System.out.println("Francés, igual 1");
        System.out.println("Español, igual 2");
        System.out.println("Alemán, igual 3");
        idioma = scan.nextInt();
        arreglo[0][x] = idioma;

        if ((idioma > IDIOMAMAX || idioma < IDIOMAMIN) && i < MAXINTENTOS) {
            System.err.println("¡ERROR!")
            i++;
        }
    } while ((idioma > IDIOMAMAX || idioma < IDIOMAMIN) && i < MAXINTENTOS);
    if (i == MAXINTENTOS) {
        System.err.println("¡ERROR!");
    } else {            
        do {                
            System.out.println("Indique Precio/hora");
            precio = scan.nextInt();

            if (precio > PRECIOMAX && i < MAXINTENTOS) { 
                i++;
            } else if (precio < PRECIOMIN && i < MAXINTENTOS) { 
                i++;
            }
        } while ((precio < PRECIOMIN || precio > PRECIOMAX) && i < MAXINTENTOS);
        if (i == MAXINTENTOS) {
            System.err.println("¡ERROR!");
        } else {
            arreglo[1][x] = precio;
            i = 0;
            System.out.println("Ver Precio medio por idioma (Sí=1 No=0)");
            ordMed = scan.nextInt();

            if (ordMed== 1) {
                for (i = 0; i < contador - 1; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < contador - i - 1; j++) {
                        if (i == arreglo[0][j]) {
                            precioMedio = precioMedio + arreglo[1][j];
                            x++;
                        }
                    }
                    if (x != 0) {
                        precioMedio = precioMedio / x;
                        System.out.println("El precio medio de  " + i + " es: " + precioMedio);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Lo que me gustaría saber es como podría sacar el precio medio de cada idioma introducido por teclado. Es decir, si pongo:

**lengua/precio**: aleman 12, ingles 4, ingles 14, ingles 20

Me quedase al final, el **precio medio** por nivel:

Inglés – 12,7 e/h; Francés – No escogida; Español – No escogida; Alemán – 12 e/h.

Principalmente, no consigo que el último condicional con los bucles for, me acaben de cuadrar y me den las medias como las busco. Me sale a 0.
Espero que puedan ayudarme.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que he podido ver en tu código el problema estaría en la variable contador, pues está inicializada a 0 y no se modifica en todo el programa. Debido a esto el bucle no realiza ninguna iteración. Además sin estar seguro, creo que la variable precio debería ser también declarada como float. Espero que ese sea el error y te haya servido.

---

Fuera de la pregunta y a modo de consejo te recomendaría tabular, comentar o estructurar el código de forma que resulte algo mas legible sobre todo la parte de los if else no solo para nosotros sino para ti mismo ya que aunque es difícil te ayudará bastante. Mucho ánimo y sigue aprendiendo.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Gracias Javier por tu respuesta y tus ánimos. ¿No te importaría poder mostrarme algun ejemplo ilustrativo para que me de alguna pista de como hacerlo?
Gracias
Saludos,

Comment: @Pedrix17 Lo siento pero no me pillas con mucho tiempo. El error en cuestión era porque al ser contador 0  nunca se cumplía la condición de inicio en los for, recuerda iterarlo según tu quieras y debería funcionar. Creo que todavía está incompleta la app por eso te recomiendo hacer primero una versión sin control de datos así te quedará un código más limpio y te será mas fácil terminarlo. Un saludo y suerte